# Admob doesn't show cross promotion banner

Tags: android, admob

Admob doesn't show cross promotion banner. Application(android) always shows third party advertisments instead of configured cross promotion banner.

Interesting detail is we have successfully configured another cross promotion banner with the same steps three months ago.

We tried to configure cross promotion in this way:

1. Create ad unit for application

   - ad type: all checked
   - frequency capping: no cap on impressions
   - ad unit name: "Test ad unit"
2. Integrate to android application

Add this line to application onCreate:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "Admob app id");
```

Add these lines to show interstitial:

```
com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd(context);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("Test ad unit id");
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    });

mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

3. Configure campaign to show cross promotion banner

   - status: enabled
   - name: test campaign
   - goal type: percantage of traffic; goal: 100%; rate: 1000000$
   - type: house ad (also we tried direct sold)
   - schedule: sep 19, 2017 - no end date
   - frequency capping: no cap on impressions
   - ad unit: "Test ad unit"
   - geo, languages, carriers, devices, demographics: all
   - ads: html 5 ad